# MVC3 Razor Passing ViewModel to Conroller List<> is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a MVC 3 applicaiton in which I pass a vewmodel from the controller to the view.  The vewmodel contains a couple of List<> properties.

```
        public ActionResult MainView()
    {
        var model = GetViewModel();
        return View("SignificantEventsView", model);
    }
 private SignificantEventsViewModel GetViewModel()
    {
        var viewModel = new SignificantEventsViewModel();
        List<County_Codes> countyCodes = GetCountyCodeList();
        List<String> stateNames = countyCodes.OrderBy(o=>o.County_st).Select(o => o.County_st ).Distinct().ToList();

        viewModel.selectedState = stateNames.FirstOrDefault();
        viewModel.CountyCodesList = countyCodes;
        viewModel.StateNames = stateNames;
        viewModel.SelectedCounties = new String[]{};
        viewModel.SelectedCountyCodes = new String[] { };
        viewModel.UnSelectedCounties = new String[] { };
        viewModel.UnSelectedCountyCodes = new String[]{};

        return viewModel;
    }
```

The View looks like this:

```
@model ServicingPortal.ViewModels.SignificantEventsViewModel
@{
      ViewBag.Title = "Significant Events";
}

<h2>SignificantEvents</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("RefreshCounties", "SignificantEvents", FormMethod.Post, new { id    = "significantEventsForm", Model }))
{
      <fieldset>
            <span class="SpanTextboxEdit"> 
            @Html.Label("states", "States")
            <br />
        <br />
            @Html.DropDownListFor(o => @Model.selectedState
                , new SelectList(Model.StateNames)
                , new { id = "stateDropDown", onchange = "submit()", name = "test" })
        </span>
    </fieldset>
        ...
}
```

When the StateDropdownList is changed the veiwmodel is passed back to the controller, but the countyCodes list is always null.

I tried adding @Html.HiddenFor(o => @Model.CountyCodesList) in the view, but it still returns null.  The only values that don't seem to be null are the primitive types such as String or String[].  Even the List stateNames is null.

I don't want to rebuild the county code list on each post back because there is substantial overhead involved. I have to create the list from all active loans in the database, of which there are thousands.

How can I get a List<> to persist from the view to the controller?

I should explain what I'm trying to acheive here.

I have a dropdown and a multiselect list box.  The dropdown contains states and the listbox contains counties filtered by the selected state.
I need to filter the listbox contents when the selected state changes.
It would make sense to perform this task on the client side, but I have not found a good solution.
I will admit my javascript skills are quite limited.
All the solutions I researched one way or another involved filtering the county list on the server side.
I can accomplish this on the server side easy enough, but I thought that since I have already built the list, why not keep it intact instead of going to the backend each time.

Comment: Out of curiosity, try adding `.ToList()` after `GetCountryCodeList()`.

Comment: Actually GetCountryCodeList() already returns List<County_Codes>

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't really do what you're trying to do. You're kind of trying to solve the wrong problem. You should look at using caching on the server side to prevent going back to the database to construct the county list every time.

Comment: I tried this route as well, but it seems that the entire viewmodel is cached.  This results in the value for the state dropown list to revert back to the original value each time.

Comment: You don't need to cache the whole ViewModel, just cache the bits you need. This isn't exact syntax, but the general idea would be: cache.Add("counties", countyCodes), viewModel.CountyCodesList = cache.Get("counties").

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using TempData.  On the postback action I can get the County List from temp data and set the ViewModel CountyCodeList to this value.

Comment: I hope that works in all situations for you because it's not really the problem that TempData is designed to solve. It also only addresses the issue for one round trip for one user. If it is really that expensive to retrieve the list of counties you should be looking at a more broad solution that would benefit every request for every user.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate what TempData was designed for?

Comment: I added an explanation of what I'm trying to achieve in the original post.  This may add some clarity to my issue.